# Possible to template without access to the server?

Tags: ee3, file-manager, template-scripting

Is it possible (or even ideal) to template or even make a file manager within Expression Engine without access to the server? I was given the challenge to this recently with no success (and ALOT of frustration). Not sure if I need to insist that I need access to the server or whether I'm just making this more complex than I need too.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your templates with the template manager. Css and js templates can also be available (but not recommended). For files you are restricted to the upload directories that exist. You'll need access to ftp to create new ones.
But i would never do a job without proper ftp and DB access.

Comment: But if your given a HTML template and told, "here.. build a simple two page site with images, videos and downloadable links without server access," you wouldn't do it? Why? Is it that much more difficult? If yes, I understand, I LIVED it. I struggled 7.5 hours trying to build this site without server access and felt like I was told to make a sand castle out of 2 ounces of sand. I'm a novice at web development and at Expression Engine, am I missing something?

Comment: Why is it not recommended to make CSS or JS templates within EE?

Comment: Because EE will evaluate these templates in the parse order. And that takes time.

Comment: Thank you, on the project provided to me, my file directories were not working, hence the need to make new file directories in order to template, but, alas, I had no server access. I guess I'll never know if there is a way to template without access to the server end when creating file managers are involved.